# Clear/Remove all connections in a Xcode project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, action, target

I'm a newbie to Xcode, Objective-C and iOS programming (fully comfortable in R however, so familiar with programming concepts).  I'm working my way through building my first app using a couple of books.

I have botched some or most connections due to misunderstanding the concept at first, and I think also renaming objects and variables has caused confusion (connections = targets and actions as I understand it).  In Xcode,

1. is there a way to remove/clear all these at once?
2. is there a tool to find the orphaned objects (ones that still need either a target or action)?
3. is there a tool to summarize all of them?  They don't really appear in raw code any place, right?  They are embedded in the .xib if I understand correctly.

I'm on OSX 10.7.2 and Xcode 4.2.1  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how deep you are in the project, you could simply create a brand new project and copy your code from the old to the new (and recreate your XIB's; the new ones would have no botched connections).

Or, you'd have to go into each of your XIB files (they're text) and you can delete the connections en masse there (look for entries like `IBToOneOutletInfo`, `IBActionInfo`, etc.).  Best to do this from within Xcode though, with the built in Interface Builder (just click on the "X"s next to the connections and actions for each object to officially disconnect them).

Comment: I'll go with editing the XIB so I can see what it looks like as well.  When I click on my file.xib, I only see the graphic layout -- what do I do to see the text/XML version?  I don't see any file items or buttons to do so, but it may be right in front of me.  Thanks.

Comment: I probably should emphasize that you really ought not to be messing with the text contents of the XIB file unless you're really feeling like you're up to the challenge.  If you hold down the "Control" key while selecting your XIB file within Xcode (in the list of files and libraries along the left side of your project), you'll see a contextual (popup menu) and one of the choices there is "Open as" ... choose "Source Code".  And good luck!